# Adding internal JAR library to WAR test in Arquillian

Tags: java, ejb, jboss-arquillian, java-ee-8

I'm trying to test with Arquillian a Java RESTful API (JAX-RS) in a `war` package. The  API in the `war` calls a method of an EJB that's located in a `jar`.

To test this, I created an Arquillian test that calls the `war` method. The test is located in a `test` folder inside the `war`. The problem is that Arquillian complains that it doesn't find a library that's called internally in the `jar` (note that this library is not in the `pom.xml`). I prefer not to add an EJB dependency in the `war`, how to add this library to Arquillian's deployment?

```
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
        .addClass(DAOException.class)
        .addClass(BeanException.class)
        .addPackages(true, "org.jooq") // <-- I had to copy this library to the war
        .setWebXML("WEB-INF/web.xml")
        .addAsDirectories("/myfolder/mypackage")  // <-- this doesn't work
        .addPackages(true, "ejb.package");
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found this [here](http://arquillian.org/guides/shrinkwrap_introduction/) and it would work for me if the `importFrom` gets a directory of files instead of a `jar` file.

```
JavaArchive roundtrip = ShrinkWrap
  .create(ZipImporter.class, "myPackageRoundtrip.jar")
  .importFrom(new File("/home/alr/Desktop/myPackage.jar"))
  .as(JavaArchive.class);
```